# Button that plots multiple line series in a chart

Tags: c#, charts, datagridview

What I wanted to do is to create a button that will plot the data from a datagridview to chart (line). The line chart corresponding to the selected data will be displayed when you click the button every time. Meanwhile, the previous display will not disappear.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace graphgrid
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int i = 2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chart1.Size = new Size(700, 400);
        ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);

        Legend legend1 = new Legend();
        chart1.Legends.Add(legend1);


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series.Add("MySeries" + i);
        chart1.Series["MySeries" + i].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series["MySeries" + i].XValueMember = "V (V)";
        chart1.Series["MySeries" + i].YValueMembers = "I (A)";
        chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Voltage";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Current";
        i++;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table);

    }
}
```

}

So far this is what I`ve done. It plots a selected column from the datagridview as the X and Y components. And it can only plot 1 line series.

Comment: If you want to show the new data in parallel you probably want to add a new Series. If you want to append the new data  to the old you should do this in the DaaSource and bind again.

Comment: how can i code the button so that it adds a new series everytime i press it?

Comment: You need to decide on a naming scheme to produce a new name each time; then a dding `chart1.Series.Add(newName); chart1.Series[newName].ChartType = ..` will do the job.

Comment: Hi! I just edited my post and changed the code. What it can do now is to make a series name and display the datagridview`s column data. My problem now is it only display the newest data, which is only one line graph. What should I change on my code? Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I forgot: You are binding to the Chart but you should be binding to the Series! QAlso you should bind with the correct column names.. Maybe you should exaplin your data a little more. What do ou mean by 'selected'?

Comment: Are you adding data to the DGV and if so how and where? If you add rows you will not be able to use data binding as that will alsways bind all rows. If you are adding them in new columns you will need to use the ew column names. If you in fact not adding ata but only select a new batch of rows, then, again, you can't use binding. You then have a choice of copying the selected data directly into the Chart.Sereis.Points.AddXY() or into a new data source to which you bind..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzRxQ07RhMQ&t=105s I referenced my code here. I  followed exactly the first two minutes on my code here.

Comment: Yes. But you still need to answer my questions. Do note that ther are  [many ways of DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766.aspx) to a Chart.. You will probably want to Bind to the Series you have created. But do tell us exactyl what will be different each time you click the button?

Comment: Sorry. Yes I`m adding data to the DGV. First I added a serviced-based database item. Then I went to the Server Explorer, looked for the database I created then added a new table named "Table". There are two contents of it named "V (V)" and "I (A)". And then went to the Data Source and added a new data source, which is the "Table". Then I put a DGV, and I choose the data source to be the "Table". And finally I added a chart and a button, and their codes is what I posted above.

Comment: What I wanted to happen is everytime I press the button, the data I Inputted to the DGV under the columns "V (V)" and "I (A)" is to be displayed as a line series in the chart. If I press it the second time, it will again display the data I inputted in a new series and the first series will not disappear. If I press it the third time, it will again display the data I inputted in a new series and the first and second series will not disappear. And so on.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ChIb62xMOcPb1t0MMffwxgynKQ8w6HQ8/view?usp=sharing here is a gif of the one I`ve done so far. It can only display one series at a time.

Comment: Ah, ok. As it is you can't see the old data because they don't exist anymore. You have bound them, not copied after all.. - This will need to create either a number of datasource to which you copy the current data and then bind them. Or, maybe simpler, not using datasources at all and add directly into the new series like I said abvove with the loop of newSeries.Points.AddXY(..)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace graphgrid
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int l = 1;
    List<float> array1 = new List<float>();
    List<float> array2 = new List<float>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Table);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateDatagridview();
        chart1.Series.Add("MySeries" + l);
        chart1.Series["MySeries" + l].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series["MySeries" + l].Points.AddXY(array1[i], array2[i]);
        }
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Voltage";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Current";
        l++;

    }

    public void updateDatagridview()
    {
        array1.Clear();
        array2.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            float va = Convert.ToSingle(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            float va2 = Convert.ToSingle(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            array1.Add(va);
            array2.Add(va2);
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Here is a gif of an example of what this project can do. Thank you @TaW for your time and effort on answering my questions! Really appreciate it!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X8Yw1cE5Zp4yVoqt1pUKS0bkIZvNRPrR/view?usp=sharing